# When Storing large block of text in a database is it better to store them in the database or as a external file?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, sqldatatypes

I'm aiming to store long item description approx 3000 char +.

Would having a external pointer to a .txt file stored in the database have any advantages; or would it be easier and quicker to place the blocks of text directly in the database.

Comment: 3000 characters is not particularly long.  You don't need to worry about storing it in the database.  If you have other reasons for storing in a file, then you might want to consider that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to store the text in the database if you want to automate typical database semantics against the data:

- ACID transactions, rollback, etc.
- Indexing
- Access privileges
- Backups
- Replication

Answer (score 0):

You can make analogy to video or large image , it’s always saved in file .

Comment: I disagree with "always".  But in the _typical_ use, namely as an image to display on a web page via `<img src=...>`, there are valid reasons for saving the image/video separately.  The url (or part of it) would be stored in the database.

Comment: @james I agree with you